# Best practice for writing text to file when abrupt program closure is likely with Python

Tags: python, csv, logging, recovery

I'm working in an environment where I'd like to leave a script running overnight but for policy reasons can not assume the PC will be left powered on (auto shutdown in an ungraceful manner after arbitrary time period).

I have a python script that is writing to a text file.  During testing when I ungracefully terminate the program on some occasions a line of text will only be partially written out to the file.  I'm also using the csv module.

Attempt at approximate code here:

```
import csv

outCSV = open("filename.txt", "a")

#more code here for writing multiline non CSV "header" block if file doesn't already exist

csvWriter = csv.writer(outCSV,lineterminator='\n')

#loop through a list, using values to derive other data for writing out later
lookupList = range(5)

for row in lookupList:
    #function to return list of data elements from web source for CSV writer, using range(100) for mock data
    outDataRow = range(100)
    csvWriter.writerow(outDataRow)
    #save after each row in case script is closed aburptly
    outCSV.flush()

print "done!"
```

I realize the above example is trivial, it probably runs too fast to reliably close the script so that the csvWriter.writerow() fails to finish writing out a line.  The actual project involves checking some web based content, where each url takes up to 15 seconds to load then writes potentially hundreds of items to a line.  Looking more for conceptual answer (i suspect the issue is when "csvWriter.writerow(outDataRow)" is still executing and the program closes).

So far the best idea I've had is to build in an error checker to go over any output (once i restart the next day) that looks for incomplete records and redo those lines.  Wondering if there is a smarter way?

P.S. I tried searching but even picking effective keywords was difficult, pardon if this is duplicate question (add keywords used to find it in the comments?)

Comment: use a namedTemporoaryFile and shutil.move doing the writing in blocks if required

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at the [signal module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/signal.html). here is a brief explanation related to your case.

When the operating system restarts, it first sends signals to all programs. That is telling programs "please close now!!". programs are responsible to clean up and close. signals are used in other things too but this is what is related to you.

In python (and others), we write a function to handle a signal, that is to clean up and exit when the signal is received. signal handling is done like this in python:

```
import signal   #you need this to handle signals
import time     #used in this simple example

#open a file
f = open ('textfile.txt', 'w')

#signal handler. it has two parameters
#signum: signal number. there are many signals each with its number
#frame: i am not really sure what this is but i guess it is used for
#       things i do not need. just a guess though
def sig_handler (signum, frame):
    #print debugging information
    print ('got', signum, 'signal, closing file...')
    #close the file before exiting
    f.close()
    print ('exiting')
    #exit. you have to write this to end the program from here
    exit (1)

#create signal handler
#when `SIGTERM` signal is received, call function `sig_handler`
#if program receive the signal without creating a handler for it, the program
#will terminate without any clean up
signal.signal (signal.SIGTERM, sig_handler)

#infinite loop. will never end unless a signal is received to stop the program
while True:
    #write to file
    print ('test line', file=f)
    #delay to simulate slow writing to file
    time.sleep (1)
```

you should know what signal is sent when the operating system shuts down or simply handle all possible signals with the same handler. i think SIGTERM is the one used to terminate processes during shut down but i am not sure.

there is 1 signal you can never handle and your program will simply be forced to close without any clean up (i am sure in unix like. it is probably present in windows). but that one is sent in rare cases (eg. program hangs and does not close after SIGTERM or other signals are sent).

hope this helps...